# How to populate empty attributes with random values from seeds.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, random

I've generated `User` model with attributes: `first_name`, `last_name`, `city`. Then, I've created 200 instances of the class using seed.rb and gem 'faker'. After all, I have added one more attribute to this model - age:string, so now in every instance of the class the age = `'nil'`. Now, I want to populate every single user with randomly generated number from range 10..99.
Here is my code from seed.rb:

```
users = User.all
users.each do |element|
    element.age = rand(10..99).to_s
end
```

When I type `rake db:seed` it seems to be successfull but when I check the database, each `age:string` is still `'nil'`. Do you have any idea what might have gone wrong?

Comment: you must persist the object, ie: `element.save` inside the block

Comment: I totally forgot about it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the value, but you don't save it. You should change your code to

```
users = User.all
users.each do |element|
  element.age = rand(10..99).to_s
  element.save!
end
```

or just

```
users = User.all
users.each do |user|
  user.update_attribute(:age, rand(10..99))
end
```

If you don't need to validate the record, the following is even faster

```
users = User.all
users.each do |user|
  user.update_column(:age, rand(10..99))
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`@Simone Carletti`'s answer is good... maybe you'd benefit from [`find_each`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/find_each):

```
User.find_each do |user|
   user.update_attribute :age, rand(10..99)
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Also, you can combine Faker with [Fabrication](http://www.fabricationgem.org/) for more *cool* seeds.

```
Faker::Name.name      #=> "Christophe Bartell"
Faker::Internet.email #=> "kirsten.greenholt@corkeryfisher.info"
```

You can use it to generate random data from `db/seed.rb`running `rake db:seed`.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The user is already using `faker`.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti Fabrication.